# Search through a column using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to  use the "IN" SQL operator but instead of a set number of defined variables, I'm trying to use a table column instead. So I've written the following, but I cannot get it work.

```
SELECT * FROM searchWithinTable
WHERE searchBy IN (Test2C.col1)
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks! (I'm using SQL Server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass "column" as a list for `in` condition, but you can pass subselect from that table/column.

Just use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM searchWithinTable
WHERE searchBy IN (select col1 from Test2C)
```

Comment: You should always use **where <column name> is not null** to avoid incorrect result.

Comment: I feel so stupid. This works, thank you very much, and again I feel rather stupid for even asking this when I look at the solution...

Comment: @anujtripathi thank you for the contribution, that helps too!

Comment: @anujtripathi not in this case. Possible null values returned by subquery will not affect where clause since `null in (null)` condition is false until you set `ANSI_NULLS off` option for database.

Comment: @BitwiseStarter: another option: `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Test2C WHERE col1 = searchBy)
`

Answer (score 0):

> use sub query instead of static value

**example:=**

```
SELECT EMPID, ENAME
FROM EMPLOYEES 
WHERE EMPID IN (SELECT EMPID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPID >200)
```